# List not resolved questions: unanswered & answered but not accepted

Tags: support, unanswered-questions, unaccepted-answer

How to list a questions for a tag which can be considered as not resolved?
so both cases:

- not answered
- answered but not accepted

Comment: Here are some [ninja filter options](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) you could apply to searches...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a search query with a tag and the `hasaccepted` modifier, [such as `[support] hasaccepted:0`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsupport%5D+hasaccepted%3A0) (which will automatically filter by questions only).

Comment: Works pretty fine, but IMO there should be a tab for it. It is more important to know which are not accepted than not answered because answers doesn't have to answer the question.

Comment: @MusX Actually, it is normally that the OP simply hasn't accepted it.